# CSS grid with aspect-ratio cells to fill height

Tags: html, css, css-grid, aspect-ratio

I want to create a css grid with fixed size (28x20) grid that fills all available height while keeping cells the same aspect ratio (1/1).

See simplified example below. Ideally this 3x3 grid would fill height and have empty space on the right side but instead it fills the width and creates a vertical scrollbar.

This only has to work on recent builds of chromium (Electron app)

Suggestions?

```css
.ctnr {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}


.cell {
  background: orange;
  aspect-ratio:1;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctnr">
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want your grid to be column oriented use `grid-auto-flow: column;`

Comment: won't this break the fixed-dimension requirement? E.g. if I apply it to the example above instead of the grid-templates it will lay out all 9 squares on one column

Comment: It is not a replacement for grid-templates, but should be added in addition to the styles you already have. That being said, it doesn't solve your problem with the sizing

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a few ideas. My solution probably isn't perfect but maybe it will help you. You can use `vh` in your grid as the basis for sizing. So if we need 3 squares per column, we can set `33vh` for columns and rows.
Also add `grid-auto-flow: column;` to make it column oriented.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1px;
  /* Maybe use something like calc(100vh / 3 - 1px) for more precise calculation */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 33vh);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 33vh);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.cell {
  background-color: #121212;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 300px) );` and chage the values around to suit your needs

Comment: this isn't viable as the window has to be resizable without the grid elements overflowing the height. This only constrains the width and height to to a size range. Make the window  too big and there will undesirable space under the grid. Make the window too small and the grid elements will overflow height again

Comment: did you try decreasing the min value and increasing the  max value?